# Cannot get data for the twitter timeline

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I am trying to load the tweets through json since I am currently making an twitter app. No sign of getting data from json twitter. I also have an null output from my array as well. Is there a possible mistake that I made using the API?

```
-(void)twitterTimeLine{
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
        {
            if (granted == YES) {
                NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {
                    ACAccountType *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];
                    NSURL *requestAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline/json"];
                    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                    [parameters setObject:@"100" forKey:@"count"];
                    [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

                    SLRequest *posts = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestAPI parameters:parameters];
                    posts.account = (ACAccount *)twitterAccount;
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
                    [posts performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *response, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){
                        array=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
                        // NSLog(@"%@",posts);
                        NSLog(@"%@",array);
                        NSLog(@"---------");


                        if (array.count !=0) {
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                                 [timelineTableView reloadData];
                                 });
                        }
                     }];
                     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                 }
                 else {
                     NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                 }
             };



         }];
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in your response error parameter?

Comment: no I am only getting an warning at                                             posts.account =twitterAccount; saying incompatible pointer type assigning to ACAount from ACAcountType.

Comment: If you want to see another code please feel free to ask.

Comment: can you check it with updated answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];
```

This might be the reason of getting warning.

Update your URL with :

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json

Comment: I was able to clear the warning but I am still not getting any data using json it is showing null

Comment: it seems like you are using the wrong URL format. pls check with above URL.

Comment: YES ATLAST! HOWEVER the username does not appear

Comment: What response you are getting now?

Comment: Im not getting anything its just displaying as it is in the storyboard

Comment: What is the response here : NSLog(@"%@",array);